# Is [0,1] closed?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, differential-topology

I thought it was closed, under the usual topology $\mathbb{R}$, since its compliment $(-\infty, 0) \cup (1,\infty)$ is open.

However, then then intersection number would not agree mod 2, since it can arbitrarily intersect a compact manifold even or odd times.

P.S. The corollary.

> $X$ and $Z$ are closed submanifolds inside $Y$ with complementary dimension, and at least one of them is compact. If $g_0, g_1: X \to Y$ are arbitrary homotopic maps, then we have $I_2(g_0, Z) = I_2(g_1, Z).$

The contradiction (my question):

> Let [0,1] be the closed manifold $Z$, and then it can intersect an arbitrary compact manifold any times, contradicting with the corollary.

---

Aneesh Karthik C's comment answered my question, so just to clarify:

I was thinking $g_0$ is one wiggle of [0,1] such that it intersects a compact manifold once, and $g_1$ is some other sort that [0,1] intersect twice. Then it contradicts with the corollary. But apparently it doesn't, because [0,1] does not satisfy the corollary as a closed manifold. By definition, a closed manifold is a type of topological space, namely a compact manifold without boundary.

Since [0,1] is not a closed manifold, it can intersect a compact manifold as much as it want, without contradicting with the theorem.

I didn't realize that [0,1] is not a closed manifold. So I thought it contradicts and that's why I ask the question.

Comment: The first line is absolutely correct. I can't make any sense of the second.

Comment: One of the assertions you're making is wrong, and it's not the one about $[0,1]$ being closed...

Comment: A closed manifold is a compact boundaryless manifold. So the last line "Let $[0,1]$ be the closed manifold $Z$"  is wrong

Comment: OH, that's exactly what confuses me, thanks so much @AneeshKarthikC! So [0,1] is not a closed manifold because it has boundary points, 0 and 1, right? Thanks again~

Comment: Yes. Quite right. In fact some of us call manifolds that are not closed, as **open** manifolds. Basically when you talk of closed manifolds you should not make reference to a mother space, for that is when confusion sets in!

Comment: So the ironly...? What do you what to say, @AneeshKarthikC?

Comment: Also, do you mind putting your comment as answer @AneeshKarthikC? I think it answered my question, and I think it is a great answer.

Comment: The question is on hold, so can't answer. Clarify your question. I can then put my comment as answer!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9642/discussion-between-jellyfish-and-aneesh-karthik-c)

Comment: It is open now @AneeshKarthikC  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closed manifold is a compact boundaryless manifold. So the last line "Let [0,1] be the closed manifold Z" is wrong, for $\partial[0,1]\ne\phi$.

Comment: @Jellyfish: Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Aneesh!!